# Should I use the ReSharper rules for naming?

Tags: c#

I have a fairly small and new MVC application I am working on. I just installed the Trial edition of ReSharper and its suggesting a few (many) name changes.

In particular it's suggesting method name changes from `getStorageAccount` to `GetStorageAccount`, local variable name changes from `_questionTable` to `questionTable` and so on.

I would like to my application to conform as much as possible. Do you suggest I spend an hour changing everything just so it's done the way ReSharper suggests. I have the time and now would be a good time to do it.

Comment: Entirely up to you. Some companies have coding guidelines that do not agree with what resharper says (me for one). Do not take resharper as gospel.

Comment: Sometimes coding rules becomes a holly war question between the development team members, so you've to decide it yourself. Anyway most standard rules make sense in general...

Comment: You kind of answered your question yourself. While it might not even matter much for the small application you are writing, it will teach you a lot about coding standards - and that will make you a better programmer. I would suggest reading up on C# Programming Standards/Best Practices. It wont even need a lot of time and there is a lot of useful info on the net, so I refrain from posting links here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I would do what ReSharper suggest. IIRC ReSharper is follwing the [.NET Naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx)

Resharper docs says that the default var usage is:

> Can change explicit to 'var' and vice versa, specifically:
>
> - In iterators: uses var except for simple types.
> - In local variables: uses var only when initializer has type usage

Comment: Interestingly I did code cleanup for one of my files and it changed all my vars to ints, strings, long etc. I'd have thought use of var looks cleaner. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Yes. It determines where it'c clear what kind of type that the variable is. I've created my own rules which is identical to the Resharper ones, except for the implicit var rule. I set `var` everywhere where it's possible.

Comment: @Robert Did it change lines like var buddy = new Person()?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say that in general it is good to follow the naming conventions of the language you're using. Which is what ReSharper suggests in this case. (EDIT: ...as long as they are not contradicting some local policy at your company etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes, following any convention is a good thing. If you're using Resharper they have a rather good conventions to follow and that's what I did. But it's up to you